# App crashes at startup

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

Alright, my app is working great in the simulator, but when I transfer the app to my iPhone it crashes at startup.  I am installing the app via cydia.  The app can be installed via this source `chrisrjones.com/repo`  The crash report can be found here - > [crash report](http://www.chrisrjones.com/files/LatestCrash.plist)  The source code for the app can be found here -> https://github.com/ipatch/KegCop

I created a shell script to code sign and build the deb package for the app, and have not had any problems with the app so far.  I have no idea what I am looking for in the crash report, as I haven't really done much looking at these things.  Also I am pretty sure this isn't a code sign bug, but I could be wrong.  The app launches for a second or two then crashes, I am pretty sure the code sign crash happens quicker than what I am experiencing.

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 on OS X 10.7.4, iOS version is 5.1.1 I am using ARC in my Xcode project.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of xcode are you using. Do you have ARC, or Manual Reference Counting? Are your header files hooked up correctly? What do the errors say? What does this app do? Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @bwheeler96 well i don't want the app crashing, for one thing.

Comment: You have a NULL pointer to something (0x000000).

Comment: @CodaFi do you know how I would find that in high level language code?

Comment: No idea.  It seems to be core data related, so look in your delegate.

Comment: how do you know its core data related?

Comment: @CodaFi, you were right, it was Core Data related. deleted the old Accounts.sqlite file then removed, the app, then reinstalled, no crash so far.

Comment: Alright, put that up as the answer and mark it as accepted to help future visitors.

Comment: @Kyle yeah I've been working on that (-.-) it's a complicated web app xP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, to fix this problem, I deleted the Accounts.sqlite file located at /var/mobile/Library/KegCop/  I then removed the app via Cydia.  I restarted the phone.  I reinstalled app via Cydia, then the app quit crashing. (yay)